# SQL table name in unicode

Tags: sql-server, unicode, ado.net

I have a SQL table created in SQL Management Studio, lets call it `dbo.国际码`.

When using SqlCommand to read from the table, how should i get an access to it?

I have tried to bind Unicode on to the socket string, but it didn't work.

And do I need to use something like collation-----Latin1_General_CI_AS?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `dbo.[国际码]` ?

Notice the square brackets `[]` around 国际码